# ng-repeat hide all elements except initial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

On my page I'm rendering the form based on api call. With help couple filters I'm hiding all elements which have 'id' in title and which equal 0, but I need to display initial element Id. I would used '$first' but the first element is checkbox value, so how can it be done? I appreciate for any help. [**applied plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kZ8fFQc4tGsYgsWbXyQ?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.upload = function (){

        $scope.rowKeys = Object.keys($scope.rowData);
        };

  });

app.filter('hide', function () {
  return function(input, arg) {
      return input.replace(arg, '');
  };
})
```

html

```
<form style="padding: 15px">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!id' | filter: '!0'" ng-model="rowValue">
      <label for="rowValue" class="col-sm-2">{{k | hide:'.name'}}:</label>
      <div class=" col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue" value="{{rowData[k]}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData" ng-disabled="!rowValue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `ng-if` for this:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <div ng-if="(thing === 'id' || thing.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
        {{thing}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I understand you a bit better.  Try `(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().indexOf('id') === -1) ? true : false`

Comment: @Anton I edited my answer to make use of `endsWith()` instead, in case one of your keys is **myRaidTeam** or something, so it doesn't get excluded without you meaning it to.  Still, it's susceptible to exclude any key ending in 'id'.

Comment: my fault it is perfectly working! thank you so much!